# Numbering custom theorem/lemma/example... with the same order

Tags: numbering, custom

I created custom theorem/definition/example formats so that they appear in colors as in the image. However, the numbering is not as I would like it to be (see first image).

[image: Wrong ordering]

Instead of as in the image, I would like to have
Theorem 1.5 ...
Definition 1.6 ...
Example 1.7 ...

The current state of the declarations are as below. I have also tried to write in definition and example "numberwithin=section" and it also does not work. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.
Thanks!

```
% Theorem
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt,    headfont=\color{red}\normalfont\bfseries,   notefont=\color{black}\mdseries\normalfont, 
    notebraces={(}{)}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %postheadspace=1em,
    headpunct={ }]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[name={Theorem}, style=mystyle,
numberwithin=section
]{thm}


% Definition
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt,   headfont=\color{blue}\normalfont\bfseries,   notefont=\color{black}\mdseries\normalfont, 
    notebraces={(}{)}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %postheadspace=1em,
    headpunct={ }]{mystyledef}
\declaretheorem[name={Definition}, style=mystyledef,
numberwithin=thm
]{defn}


% Example
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt,   headfont=\color{olive}\normalfont\bfseries,   notefont=\color{black}\mdseries\normalfont, 
    notebraces={(}{)}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    %postheadspace=1em,
    headpunct={ }]{mystyleexa}
\declaretheorem[name={Example}, style=mystyleexa,
numberwithin = thm
]{exa}
```

Comment: You don't want `numberwithin=thm`, but `numberlike=thm`.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!